# Remove preceding or following newline if a conditional directive is empty

Tags: freemarker

Suppose I have a template like this:

```
some long text

<#if some_condition>
more text
<#elseif another_condition>
different more text
</#if>

trailing long text
```

If `some_condition` or `another_condition` is true, then I get expected output:

```
some long text

more text

trailing long text
```

But if both conditions are false, then I get an extra empty line:

```
some long text


trailing long text
```

I would prefer to have only one empty line in such case:

```
some long text

trailing long text
```

I can achieve this by putting an empty line inside each branch of the condition:

```
some long text
<#if some_condition>

more text
<#elseif another_condition>

different more text
</#if>

trailing long text
```

But this makes the template really ugly.

Is there a way to make Freemarker remove an empty line before or after an empty directive block?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Generating output that's truly whitespace-sensitive (like plain-text documents that humans will read) is generally not practical in FreeMarker, unless the template is quite trivial. What you can do sometimes is post-processing the output, like in this case, remove duplicate line-breaks, but of course that only works if you know that there's never a duplicate line-break intentionally.

By the way, it's a problem with template engines in general. The intent of the template author is often not clear, as the template contains both template source code formatting, and output formatting. And the rabbit hole runs deep, if you also want proper indentation, etc.